# Get Storing updated rows and previous rows as well

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's suppose I have table as :

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4


  abc        12         23          34

  abc        01         12          45
```

I am looking for query something like

insert into table(column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4) values(List of updated rows i.e select (do some logic here of changing value of column_1) from where column_1='abc')

Output should be as :-

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4


  abc        12         23          34

  abc        01         12          45

  xyz        12         23          34

  xyz        01         12          45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with another select from you insert. it not necessary to use insert into ... (...) values(..). You can use select as well as your value.

```
insert into table(column1,column2,column3,column4)
select 'xyz' as column1,column2,column3,column4 
from table
where column1 = 'abc'
```